# Issue with converting date to yyyy-mm-dd - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

im getting an error when trying to convert the date to yyyy-mm-dd

Can anyone help here

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['20150122', '20160234']})
pd.to_datetime(df,format='%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)
```

Error

> "ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month] is missing"

Expected outcome

```
0 2015-01-22
1 2016-02-15
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['year'])`

Comment: Those strings are `YYYYMMDD`, not `YYYY-MM-DD`